# Where is pollenkitt secreted?

Tags: plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, flowering

Where is the pollenkitt material secreted? I think the *tapetum* would be a good candidate, since it provides nutrition to the pollen grains.

Comment: This question may be closed, but I can't find the answer on Google Scholar. If it is closed as homework it seems to be difficult homework! I think this question deserves attention.

Comment: Thanks for paying attention towards my question. I really think it's tapetum but yeah I couldn't find any statement in support of this.

Comment: Pollen kit is secreted by tapetum

Comment: You'll find it in [University Botany by Reddy](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SuQJeFkYoRIC&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=pollen+kit+material&source=bl&ots=3phln03tfp&sig=4USIh8qsV6TE4EFYnXc4v3VUkD4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj_aim-ezTAhXERo8KHYohDJ8Q6AEIUTAI#v=onepage&q=pollen%20kit%20material&f=false) shows up on first Google web search.

Answer (score 1):

The correct name of the coating is *"pollenkitt"*, not *"pollen kit"* (I edited your question accordingly).

From the book *"Biology of pollen"* (Shukla, Vijayaraghavan and Chaudhry, 1998):

> The term **pollenkitt** is used for the oily, pigmented and sticky coating deposited on the pollen grain surface during the final stages of maturation. (emphasis mine)

That may explain why you and others struggled to find an answer in Google/Google Scholar.

Back to your question: there are two types of adhesive coats in pollen grains:

- Pollenkitt
- Tryphine

Pollenkit is the most common one and, as tryphine, it is secreted by the tapetum.

According to Pacini and Hesse (2005):

> Two types of sticky pollen coat material exist in angiosperms, **both produced by the anther tapetum**. Pollenkitt is the most common adhesive material present around pollen grains of almost all angiosperms pollinated by animals, whereas tryphine seems to be restricted only to Brassicaceae. (emphasis mine)

---

Sources:

- [Pacini, E. and Hesse, M. (2005). Pollenkitt – its composition, forms and functions. Flora - Morphology, Distribution, Functional Ecology of Plants, 200(5), pp.399-415.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0367253005000642)
- [Shukla, A., Vijayaraghavan, M. and Chaudhry, B. (1998). Biology of pollen. New Dehli: APH Publ. Corp.](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=jfSlwa0BnDgC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=pollenkitt&source=bl&ots=_smJTN3ZWJ&sig=1L33lMRraWvwE0ghAPGh6wLcGNQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfgLbUkv7XAhXMjJQKHT39ARkQ6AEIVTAG#v=onepage&q=pollenkitt&f=false)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's Tapetum.Pollen Kit is made up of Hydrophobic pollen attractant and tryphine(A mixture of hydrophilic substances)

Comment: Hi Welcome to BIO.SE. We ask that all answers on this site provide support /references (from reputable sources). See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for a guide to writing good answers